# Getting error about ImageMagick With Python/MoviePy when I try add text clip

Tags: python-3.x, file, video, imagemagick, moviepy

I am using python 3.8.5 as well as the latest version of imagemagick and moviepy

error (vs code):

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\edgib102\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\moviepy\video\VideoClip.py", line 1137, in __init__
    subprocess_call(cmd, logger=None)
  File "C:\Users\edgib102\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\moviepy\tools.py", line 46, in subprocess_call     
    proc = sp.Popen(cmd, **popen_params)
  File "C:\Users\edgib102\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\subprocess.py", line 854, in __init__
    self._execute_child(args, executable, preexec_fn, close_fds,
  File "C:\Users\edgib102\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\subprocess.py", line 1307, in _execute_child
    hp, ht, pid, tid = _winapi.CreateProcess(executable, args,
FileNotFoundError: [WinError 2] The system cannot find the file specified

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "c:/Users/edgib102/source/repos/Reddit-tts-video/Python/GetComments.py", line 40, in <module>
    TextClip = TextClip('TextTxt', fontsize=100, color = 'white')
  File "C:\Users\edgib102\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\moviepy\video\VideoClip.py", line 1146, in __init__
    raise IOError(error)
OSError: MoviePy Error: creation of None failed because of the following error:

[WinError 2] The system cannot find the file specified.

.This error can be due to the fact that ImageMagick is not installed on your computer, or (for Windows users) that you didn't specify the path to the ImageMagick binary in file conf.py, or that the path you specified is incorrect
```

Code:

```
TextClip = TextClip('TextTxt', fontsize=100, color = 'white')
TextClip = TextClip.set_position('center').set_duration(10)
```

Any help at all would be much appreciated, also full code [here](https://hastebin.com/ixazahihoq.properties)

Comment: Did you install ImageMagick 6 or 7?  MoviePy may need IM 6 or it may need IM 7 and you have installed the wrong one. On Windows, to get IM 6, I believe, you need to install the legacy components from the install window.

Comment: I checked, and it was IM 7. So would I need IM 6?

Comment: `@Eden Gibson` Check the requirements for MoviePy. But that seems likely.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Solved.  Just need to set the `magick.exe` file path as the variable inside default_config.py. You can find it in the moviepy folder.

Comment: Which default_config.py do you mean? Can you provide a full solution by showing the added code-line please?

Answer (score 2):

Add the `magick.exe` path to `IMAGEMAGICK_BINARY` in config_defaults.py.

By default it should look like this

```
IMAGEMAGICK_BINARY = os.getenv('IMAGEMAGICK_BINARY', 'auto-detect')
```

After

```
IMAGEMAGICK_BINARY = os.getenv('IMAGEMAGICK_BINARY', 'C:\\Program Files\\ImageMagick_VERSION\\magick.exe')
```